# Is it feasible to replace the apricot jam in a sacher torte with apricot preserves?

Tags: baking, cake

For some reason, none of the local markets or stores have any apricot jam or jelly. Only apricot preserves. They stand there on the shelves, surrounded by the myriad jams and jellies of other fruit/berry categories. Is it ok to use preserves, or is there a way to make preserves more suitable for a sacher torte? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point of the apricot jam is not to be tasted, but to create a kind of barrier between the sponge and the icing. So my first choice would be by texture, not by fruit. I would try getting a jam of very soft and uniform type, from some mild-tasting fruit that would be as unnoticeable as possible in the finished cake.

If you want to use the apricot preserves, make sure that you get some thickened ones, not something that's the "fruit in almost liquid syrup" kind. You may consider running it to a blender. Ideally, you'd also heat it up and cool down once so the pectin can re-bind it into a smooth mass. But that's quite a bit of effort for a small benefit, so you can also skip it.

Comment: The technical term for this in German is [_aprikotieren_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprikotieren), which in Enlish appearently is [Nappage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nappage). Redcurrant jelly, as mentioned on Wikipedia, makes sense, too.

Comment: Agreed, better use a different fruit jam than a different apricot product. The jam part is more important then the particular fruit flavor here.

Comment: I've only had sacher torte twice, both times in Berlin, and both times it had a very fruity apricot taste - in fact it tasted much more like apricot preserve had been used than apricot jam - is this unusual? Thinking about it, it's possible that both pieces came form the same source (either the Edeka chain store or the deli in Karstadt [we went to both, both times]) so maybe my sample size is really "one" which I admit is less than exhaustive...

Comment: @Spratty: as an Austrian, I strongly recommend that when you get the real thing [at Café Sacher in Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Sacher), you do *not* tell them about getting "Sachertorte" in Berlin. Viennese waiters are experts in delivering excruciating disdain with body language only.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - noted with gratitude :-)  I don't know why, but I had always assumed it was a German thing; maybe it's the ubiquity of it in Berlin (I'm not widely travelled in Germany an have never been to Austria). I live in fear of committing this sort of gaffe in real life so forewarned is forearmed :-)

Comment: In similar situations I've used home made whitecurrant jelly. Whitecurrants are as full of seeds as redcurrants but with a sweeter and much more neutral flavour so whether making jam or sorbet I always sieve them. A smooth plum jam ought to work too. The quantity is small enough that so long as you avoid strong/distinctive fruit flavours and lumps it will be fine. Sometimes in the UK a special smooth apricot jam is seen sold in the home baking section for precisely this sort of thing.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I found some high quality apricot preserves which is nice and thick, not at all runny. I'll be using that, and if I have time, might even use your method making jam out of it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ChrisH not simply plum - I actually thought a jam from Mirabellen might be the closest thing. The catch is that it's likely more difficult to source in most countries than apricot jam.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  Just use the preserves, it'll be fine.

If the preserves have very large pieces of apricot in them, then chop them up.